# ESP8266 warning: espcomm_sync failed error: espcomm_open failed UBUNTU 18.04

Tags: drivers, usb, usb-modem

Can't force upload sketch from arduino IDE.

```
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

dmseg

```
[ 4980.110605] usb 3-4: new full-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[ 4980.305550] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=10c4, idProduct=ea60
[ 4980.305556] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4980.305561] usb 3-4: Product: CP2102 USB to UART Bridge Controller
[ 4980.305565] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Silicon Labs
[ 4980.305569] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 0001
[ 4980.317468] cp210x 3-4:1.0: cp210x converter detected
[ 4980.319521] usb 3-4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0

lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 10c4:ea60 Cygnal Integrated Products, Inc. CP210x UART Bridge / myAVR mySmartUSB light
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 24ae:1100  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Settings in Arduino IDE

```
Board NodeMCULuA 1.0
CPU 80 Mhz
Upload Speed 115200
Flash Size 4M(1m SPIFFS)
Programmer AVR ISP
```

Provided access to the ttyUSB0 by command `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`

Previously worked on 16.04.
What can be the problem and how to solve it?
Behavior chip also changed. Earler diode only flashed when sketch was uploading, now is always on till the sketch start uploading and switched off when error is displayed.

Any help will be usefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that you are member of `dialout` group.
If not please add yourself to this group by running `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`, log-out and log-in again.

For more predictable results you may try to run [`esptool.py`](https://github.com/espressif/esptool) directly to check that your board is alive:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install esptool

esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 chip_id
```

You will get output which is similar to shown below:

- ESP8266 example

  ```
  $ esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 chip_id
  esptool.py v2.3.1
  Connecting....
  Detecting chip type... ESP8266
  Chip is ESP8266EX
  Features: WiFi
  Uploading stub...
  Running stub...
  Stub running...
  Chip ID: 0x01234567
  Hard resetting via RTS pin...
  ```
- ESP32 example

  ```
  $ esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 chip_id
  esptool.py v2.3.1
  Connecting....
  Detecting chip type... ESP32
  Chip is ESP32D0WDQ6 (revision (unknown 0xa))
  Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, VRef calibration in efuse
  Uploading stub...
  Running stub...
  Stub running...
  Chip ID: 0x01234567890a
  Hard resetting via RTS pin...
  ```

If it does not help - check your wiring, board temperature, cable and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did...

1. Install Arduino using scripts from [the Arduino Website](https://www.arduino.cc/) (preferably run the `install.sh` as sudo)
2. Run the arduino from terminal as sudo:

   sudo arduino

Everything worked after this...

**Note:**
'sudo arduino' and 'arduino' launch different environments of IDE so make sure you don't waste time setting up one without sudo.