# Ubuntu 18.04, Arduino 1.8.5, NodeMCU v1 will not flash even with all requirements met. Why?

Tags: arduino

Before you mark as duplicate I have read everything I can find, and done the following.

1) I have added myself to dialout group, then logged out, then back in, chmod 0666, even 0777 /dev/ttyUSB0.

2) I have done this, as suggested in [ESP8266 warning: espcomm_sync failed error: espcomm_open failed UBUNTU 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1041190/85695):

```
~$ esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 chip_id
esptool.py v2.5.1
Serial port /dev/ttyUSB0
Connecting....
Detecting chip type... ESP8266
Chip is ESP8266EX
Features: WiFi
MAC: 60:01:94:5d:4d:9d
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Chip ID: 0x005d4d9d
Hard resetting via RTS pin...
```

Passing grade there!

3) I have tried 7 different boards that were pulled from new packages.

4) I have tried every baud rate in settings.

5) I have tried every possible combination of settings for NodeMCU v1 and v0.9, just in case.

6) Board temps and wiring pass all checks, this is not a duplicate issue because all the steps in your linked issue have been tested, yet the error persists.

I still get the following error every time I try to upload via Arduino 1.8.5

```
error: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB0
An error occurred while uploading the sketch

error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

**Why? Is Arduino app 1.8.5 buggy in Ubuntu 18.04?**

Frustration level is at smash with hammer. Please tell me there is something I missed.

Oh the kicker, these boards will flash on a Mac Pro perfectly, so I know it's isolated to the Arduino app on Ubuntu only.

Comment: @N0rbert Board temps and wiring pass all checks, this is not the same issue because all the steps in your linked issue have been tested, yet the error persists. How do you think I passed the checks for esptool.py without first consulting your linked question? This is some other problem. All my NodeMCU boards will flash on OS X with the same USB cable, but not as described above if you even read the issue in full. Maybe there is a bug in Ubuntu, or in the Arduino app version mentioned above? Anyone else have actual insight rather than not reading and marking duplicate when it is not duplicate?

Comment: to avoid this sort of confusion in the future, it helps if you explicitly mention that you've seen the solutions from a similar post and that they didn't help you.

Comment: It may also help if the first line in the post is actually read, where it states, "Before you mark as duplicate I have read everything I can find, and done the following.", then if the entire post is read following that before flagging as a duplicate. What do you think those words were written to mean? How much more explicit does my language need to be? Do we really need to dissect this entire post to gain basic reading comprehension? Is this conjecture to be expected for every issue one may encounter? If you do not have a possible solution, please do not waste our time mutually. Thank you.

Comment: Wow. _You_ asked a moderator to intervene and I did, doing exactly what you wanted. I also tried to give you advice on how to avoid the same thing happening in the future: link to the posts from this site you have read since "I read everything I can find" is not very informative, because we don't know if you found the possible duplicate. I can't control how others choose to vote, and neither can you. All you can do is try to avoid confusion by being explicit. You can take my advice in the spirit it was intended or pick a fight with me instead. Your call.

Comment: Updating to Arduino 1.8.6 fixed the problem. My advice is don't use Arduino 1.8.5 on Ubuntu platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Arduino 1.8.5 Linux. Updating to Arduino 1.8.6 Linux resolved my problem. If anyone else is having this issue, please update or downgrade to 1.8.4. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This was on 64-bit architecture to be absolutely clear.