# Failed to attached usb (esp8266)

Tags: boot, 16.04, usb, virtualbox

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with VBM Version 6.0.10 r132072 (Qt5.6.2).

When I attached the USB (esp8266) I've got failure error to attached the USB
even when using:

```
ls -al /dev/tty*
```

Note that the usb is shown in the USB list bar but when I chose it I got this error:

```
tail -f /var/log/kern.log
```

And when I chose the USB from the USB list in the selection bar nothing happened.

Comment: have you the Guest Additions installed on the VM ?

Comment: yes already installed and mounted , but this error exist

Comment: You need to attach USB device to the VM temporary or by using USB filter (see [this screenshot](https://askubuntu.com/a/1124731/66509)) and then use it on VM. Then follow detection procedure from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041323/66509). It is is unclear what do you mean by "`tail -f /var/log/kern.log`" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many thanks for the people that help me to find the solution.
the solution is with the registry file called "upperfilters" which inflecting the VM so when